# Analyze NeoVim Performance Bottlenecks

Tags: neovim, performance

My Vim is kinda slow for nearly everything. Opening a file takes five seconds, it flickers when I move up and down NerdTree and sometimes when I switch windows or tabs, it freezes for dozens of seconds.

I have a lot of plugins enabled, plus webpack watch running. I have htop running on a separate monitor, and sometimes the 4 CPUs go 100% when I save a file(that's because of webpack), so this bottleneck is understandable.

But the others cited above are not. How do I get to know what exactly is causing these bottlenecks in my Vim? Is there a way to know this without experimenting disabling plugins, etc?

Comment: Does it happens also for short files? Typically, the syntax highlighter can be slow for big files.

Comment: Good point! Files that are not .js open instantly

Comment: Then don't use such big files, or turn off somehow the syntax highlighter for them :-)

Comment: remove plugins from your vimrc, half at a time until the performance improves.  continue until the worst plugins are identified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: run `vim --startuptime profile` and work for a bit. (To purely measure time from "enter" to "open and ready", use `vim --startuptime profile +q`.)

I used this and a single command quite successfully to cut my startup time by 1/3rd.

1. First, I collected the profile, as shown above.
2. Then I "analyzed" it by putting the slowest bits at the top:

```
:/VIM STARTING/,$ sort! f /  [^ ]*  /
```

(Handy trick: put `:command StartupAnalyze /VIM STARTING/,$ sort! f /  [^ ]*  /` in your vimrc and you won't have to remember how to write the command next time.)

3. (This part is specific to me) I found out that, of the nearly 300ms it took my vim to start on my laptop, 100ms were just from `:runtime ftplugin/man.vim` (to access `:Man`) and another 100ms were from a poorly designed plugin script I had. I refactored the script and changed my `:runtime` command to hotload the `:Man` command like

```
command -nargs=+ -complete=shellcmd Man delcommand Man | runtime ftplugin/man.vim | <mods>Man <args>
```

and suddenly I was averaging 100ms startup: everything felt snappier. (My other similar laptop averages 200ms with the same setup, so some machine variability is expected.)

---

Others have recommended tuning down the amount of plugins you have installed. This is certainly one way to reduce your bottlenecks! But, for the record, I have 72 plugins installed. The reason vim starts up so fast is that most of them are using `autoload` effectively; defining a handful of commands or mappings is pretty fast. Of course, startup time is not the same as everyday bottlenecks. For that, I would consider using more vim9 or more lua, as the case may be. I would also second removing plugins: some you probably just don't need; you could find a way to work differently and get rid of some of the bloat; or you could implement smaller versions that do only what you need.

---

You mention `.js` files specifically. Try `vim --startuptime profile <your-slow-js-file> +q`, or even leave it running and quit later. Analyze that. See what's taking so long to load. Syntax? A synchronous LSP that should really be async? Some plugin that's doing too much? If other files are snappy, then this indicates the problem lies here.

For what it's worth, I had the same problem with markdown files—they were orders of magnitude slower than other types of files. I was able to track down that markdown files spent lots of time sourcing all the included syntax definitions (useful for having syntax highlighting inside triple-backtick blocks). I had about 8 languages in the "support triple-backtick" configuration; removing those entirely sped up editing markdown files significantly, and now I just live with the fact that I don't have syntax highlighting in those little blocks.

Answer (score 0):

One plugin that notably improved my neovim startup time is [filetype.nvim](https://github.com/nathom/filetype.nvim) the speed test measured 175x faster filetype detection for neovim.

This plugin is a replacement for the included filetype.vim that is sourced on startup. The purpose of that file is to create a series of autocommands that set the filetype variable depending on the filename. The issue is that creating autocommands have significant overhead, and creating 800+ of them as filetype.vim does is a very inefficient way to get the job done.

Comment: I don't think this is realistic. In my own configuration file, filetype.vim takes 003.523 ms. In any case, a similar approach was merged in neovim 0.7 (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/16600)

Comment: Nice to see the exchange of ideas between vim and neovim despite some conflict in some cases. The old vim code can be seen [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/filetype.vim), it had hundreds of auto commands.